# how to move Application Insights customEvents table to postgres database?

Tags: botframework, azure-sql-database, azure-application-insights, azure-postgresql, bot-framework-composer

This is for a project on Bot Framework Composer (not SDK, so i'm using built in telemetry export settings).

I am looking for the best way to store event logs from bot conversations for analysis.  From what I've researched, the method recommended is going through Application Insights, which I activated and tested.  The data I require seems to be all captured in table `customEvents`.

The issue is I need to be able manipulate the data for analysis. But in Application Insights it's read only (and possibly purge via API).  I need to be able to add tables, edit text, etc. I have a lot of experice with postgreSQL so that's my first choice for bot log storage.

So my question is, what is the efficient way to get the `customEvents` data table that is in application insights to a postgres database?  From what I see, application insights only exports to azure storage?  But that does not have a database option.  And if I understand some of the pipelines suggested, they copy data to storage, and then copy to a database.  Isn't that a lot of storage cost, as same data will be in application insights, storageBlobs AND postgres?

What is the best pipeline?  The goal is to have non-redundant pipeline that transfers event data that is in 'customEvents' to a postgres table with same columns.

(If there is a way to redirect data that goes to `customEvents` in application isights directly to postgres table that would be perfect too. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such to redirect data from application insights directly into postgres table.

The first solution is [continuous export to azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry) as you know. Storage blob does not cost very much and you can clear the old data periodically to reduce the cost.

Another way is to use the [application insights query api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart). To do that, you need to write your own logic to query the custom events from application insights, then insert them into your DB by your code.